# MariaDB -DateTime/TimeZone Question - Not converting to correct Timezone

Tags: datetime, mariadb, timestamp, timezone

Apologies for what may be a silly question (I am very new to MariaDB!)

I am working with a web dev that is sending records from wordpress gravity forms through zapier to my mariadb database.

The web dev sent me the sql query to create the table in mariadb for him to insert the records into. the two fields in question are 'entry_date' and 'date_updated'. In the sql query table creation, the web dev, lists these 2 fields as datetime type fields.

What I found when the records started to come through is that the datetime for both fields were in UTC rather than my local time zone. I changed the data type to string to see exactly what is coming across and i am getting this through '2023-08-21T01:12:15+10:00'. I wanted to check to ensure that it isnt my timezone set up and everything is set up to 'Australia/Melbourne'.

Ive done lots of troubleshooting, i've also changed the field type to timestamp instead of datetime. This stopped the records from coming across to the database so I did a bit of google and executed the below

```
`SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global, @@SESSION.sql_mode session;
SET sql_mode = '';
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';

SET SESSION SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES'`
```

With this change, the records started to come through into the database with timestamp field type however the date/time is still in UTC.

I am really unsure where I am going wrong.. starting to think it is something to do with how the dates are coming through into my mariadb, is this the correct format for a date/time that can be converted to a local time zone?

'2023-08-21T01:12:15+10:00'

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: What do you want to change about the date with that time zone?

Comment: What does `SELECT NOW()` return?

Comment: re `2023-08-21T01:12:15+10:00`, mysql or mariadb datetime fields do *not* store a timezone or offset, just a date and time.  that +10:00 is coming from your client.  you *should* always store a UTC date and time, and convert to and from whatever timezone you want for entry/display purposes.  you should *avoid* timestamp type fields, as they convert to and from the timezone of the database connection session for you, which can be hard to deal with and make it hard to unambiguously see the data

Comment: can you expand on "come through"?  what exactly are you doing to insert/read the data?  what client/orm/libraries are in play?

Comment: oh, I see, the ...+10:00 is what you are trying to insert?  recent versions of mysql support datetime literals having an offset which is immediately applied to produce a utc value (so inserting `2023-08-21T01:12:15+10:00` actually inserts `2023-08-20 15:12:15`).  mariadb, at least as of 11.1.1, does *not* support this.  you want to do `convert_tz('2023-08-21T01:12:15','+10:00','+00:00')` instead.

Comment: Thank you all
The Select now returns the unadjusted UTC date

I am using HeidiSQL and PowerBI

Ah i see. The reason as to why I want to convert it with the +10:00 is because I am exporting the data to PBX via on premise data gateway. I am hoping to automate the refresh, so the refresh will be done with the PowerBI server which is in UTC so converting the timezone in PBX is an issue. I need to ideally have the date/time converted to my local timezone by the time I import the data into PowerBI

Using convert_tz is also a no go as i cannot create a custom query in PowerBI to MariaDB.